# Plus sign and minus sign as superscripts in bmatrix

Tags: formatting, matrices

As the title says I am trying to write a plus or minus as superscripts for various particle names in a `bmatrix`, but it does not work. I have searched for solutions, but only came up with one, which should work, but doesn't. Now it really bothers why `LaTeX` does not have this feature built in, that seems really silly, but maybe there is a good reason.

My code is:

```
%various packages
\newcommand{\minus}[1]{{#1}^{\scalebox{0.8}{-}}}
\newcommand{\plus}[1]{{#1}^{\scalebox{0.6}{\!+}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \pi^{\plus} & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{document}
```

the error i get is "Argument of `\plus` has an extra `}`. `\par \pi^{\plus}` and the error repeats in my log - maybe 50 of the same errors but only on the same line.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Macro `\plus` is defined having one argument, but it is used without argument. Likely, `\plus{\pi}` is the intended usage of the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `\plus` and `\minus` to *not* take an argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.8}{$-$}}
\newcommand{\plus}{\scalebox{0.6}{$+$}}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{bmatrix}
  \pi^{\plus} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & \pi^{\minus} & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \pi^{\plus}
\end{bmatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

I've updated the definition slightly, ensuring that `+` and `-` are taken as math binary operators.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works and from your explanation i also see why. Simple and fast help, i appreciate it!

Comment: Does anyone know why this is not standard in LaTeX?

Comment: @Alex: What is this? `\plus` and `\minus`? It's because not everyone use it in your way.

Comment: I understand that but i was thinking that a simple solution such as \+ would be useful to those who use it, without bothering those who do not use it. It works the same way with a lot of other special characters. Then again, that is just my opinion. Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @Alex: For what it's worth, ``\-`` is an existing control sequence.